# How to use the same font for all fields of a table

Tags: tables, fonts

I have a table that for each text I have to rewrite \sffamily to use sansarif font, similar to the following:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\begin{document} 
\arrayrulecolor{blue} 
\begin{tabular}{l|lll}  
& \sffamily{text} & \sffamily{text} & \sffamily{text} \\ 
\hline 
\textcolor{green}{\sffamily{text}} & \sffamily{text} & \sffamily{text} & \sffamily{text}\\ 
\hline 
\sffamily{text} & \sffamily{text} & \sffamily{text} & \sffamily{text}\\ 
\hline 
\textcolor{purple}{\sffamily{text}} & \sffamily{text} & \sffamily{text} & \sffamily{text}\\ 
\hline 
\textcolor{blue}{\sffamily{text}} & \sffamily{text} & \sffamily{text} & \sffamily{text}\\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to use the \sffamily for all fields in this table without having to rewrite it like above?

Comment: Off-topic: `\sffamily` is a switch, and hence doesn't take an argument. Thus, do write either `\textsf{text}` or `\sffamily text`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

make a group with table (for example with inserting table into float `table`, or form environment `center`) add before table command `\sffamily`. It will have "influence" only in this group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{center}
\arrayrulecolor{blue}
\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{l|lll}
& text & text & text \\
\hline
\textcolor{green}{text} & text & text & text\\
\hline
text & text & text & text\\
\hline
\textcolor{purple}{text} & text & text & text\\
\hline
\textcolor{blue}{text} & text & text & text\\
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\lipsum[22]
\end{document}
```

**Eddit:**

- considered is @leandriis comment (thank you) and show, how `\sffamily` is active only inside some group.
- considered @barbarabeeton comment and correct errors in above item (thank you for pointing on them)

Comment: +1. You might, however, want to explicityl mention that `\sffamily` is only local to the table because you also used the `center` environment. Otherwise, enclosing `\sffamily` and the whole `tabular` environment in a set of `{}` would be needed.

Comment: @leandriis, you are right. I will extend answer with your comment asap

Comment: `\sffloat`?  I think you mean `\sffamily`.  Also, the "locally" is in effect because `center` forms a local (closed) group.  (Perhaps you were thinking of "float" because floats are also local groups.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, you are right. Corrected now. Thank you very much!